# WPML how to add a featured image without duplicate to a translated post (wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress, post, wpml, wordpress-featured-image

I translated a post using WPML.
The problem is that it doesn't add a featured image to the translated post.
It takes up too many size to duplicate images using a WPML media transltion, 
so I'd like to add a featured image without duplicate to a tranlsated post (wordpress).
Would you please let me know how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried any code till now? if yes then please share your snippet code related to that for detail explanation

Comment: it is possible with custom code

Comment: Read the docs: "WPML Media Translation doesn’t duplicate any files on your site. Duplication here means that new entries are created in the database with your translated image captions, titles, meta text, and other information." - [from here](https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/media-translation/)

Comment: Hi @wpdevloper_j : Thank you for your help. I didn't know I can solve it with a custome code. You gave me idea and I solve it, thank you : )

Comment: Hi @montrealist: Thank you for your help. I tried the plugin, I don't know why but it duplicated images. I solve the problem with a cumstom code, thank you : )

Answer (score 1):

In case there is someone who needs this. 
I solved the problem using the foolowing code.

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'my_duplicate_on_publish' );
function my_duplicate_on_publish( $post_id ) {
    global $post;
    // don't save for autosave
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    // dont save for revisions
    if ( isset( $post->post_type ) && $post->post_type == 'revision' ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    
    if ($post->post_type=='your-post-type') {
           
        //we need this to avoid recursion see add_action at the end
        remove_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'my_duplicate_on_publish' );
    
        // make duplicates if the post being saved
        // #1. itself is not a duplicate of another or
        // #2. does not already have translations
    
        $is_translated = apply_filters( 'wpml_element_has_translations', '', $post_id, $post->post_type );
    
        if ( !$is_translated ) {
            do_action( 'wpml_admin_make_post_duplicates', $post_id );
        }
    
       //must hook again - see remove_action further up
       add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'my_duplicate_on_publish' );
   
    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy (add a record in the db) the featured image for the translated post editing the **wpml-config.xml** file:

```
<wpml-config>
    <custom-fields>
        <custom-field action="copy">_thumbnail_id</custom-field>
    </custom-fields>
</wpml-config>
```

https://wpml.org/documentation/support/language-configuration-files/